# Three-way join with Tumbling window on Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a single source stream that contains 3 different types of events. For each event type, I need some of their fields.

Then, I need to emit an enriched result of a new event type, made of the parts of the other 3 events

```
source (A, B, C) ->  sink (D)
```

There is a field that can be used to join A and B, and another field that can be used to join (A + B) and C

**What I have so far**

The main code I am using for the processing pipeline looks like this

```java
       /*
        * Use event time processing
        */

        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);
        env.getConfig().setAutoWatermarkInterval(5000);


        final DataStream<BaseEvent> inputStream = env
                .addSource(eventSource)

       /*
        * Assign watermarks
        */
       final DataStream<BaseEvent> sortedInputStream = inputStream
               .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy
                       .<BaseEvent>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                       .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getEventTimestamp())
                       .withIdleness(Duration.ofSeconds(30)));
        
        /*
         * Filter events by type and fork into separate streams
         */
        final DataStream<TypeOneEven> typeOneStream = sortedInputStream
                .filter(e -> TYPE_ONE.toString().equals(e.getEventType()))
                .keyBy(new BaseEventKeySelector<>())
                .map(baseEventToTypeOneEventMapFunction)
                .keyBy(new TypeOneEventKeySelector());

        final DataStream<TypeTwoEvent> typeTwoStream = sortedInputStream
                .filter(e -> TYPE_TWO.toString().equals(e.getEventType()))
                .keyBy(new BaseEventKeySelector<>())
                .map(baseEventToTypeTwoEventMapFunction)
                .keyBy(new TypeTwoEventKeySelector());

        final DataStream<TypeThreeEvent> typeThreeStream = sortedInputStream
                .filter(e -> TYPE_THREE.toString().equals(e.getEventType()))
                .keyBy(new BaseEventKeySelector<>())
                .map(baseEventToTypeThreeEventMapFunction)
                .keyBy(new TypeThreeEventKeySelector());

        /*
         * Join TypeOne and TypeTwo on interaction
         */
        final DataStream<Tuple2<TypeOneEven, TypeTwoEvent>> firstJoin = typeOneStream
                .join(typeTwoStream)
                .where(new TypeOneEventKeySelector())
                .equalTo(new TypeTwoEventKeySelector())
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
                .apply(new TypeOneTypeTwoJoinFunction());

        /*
         * Join previous stream with TypeThree
         */
        final DataStream<Tuple3<TypeOneEven, TypeTwoEvent, TypeThreeEvent>> secondJoin = firstJoin
                .join(typeThreeStream)
                .where(new TypeOneTypeTwoKeySelector())
                .equalTo(new TypeThreeKeySelector())
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(1)))
                .apply(new AllTypesJoinFunction());

        /*
         * Convert join results into EnrichedType events, send to sink
         */
        secondJoin
                .map(enrichedEventMapFunction)
                .addSink(enrichedEventSink);
```

All Map functions are `RichMapFunction<IN, OUT>` that convert BaseEvent to a concrete type.

All Join functions are `JoinFunction<IN1, IN2, OUT>` that generate tuples based on the input.

The last `enrichedEventMapFunction` is a `RichMapFunction<IN, OUT>` that takes care of grabbing the fields from the tuple elements to build a `EnrichedTypeEvent`.

**The problem**

Overall, the logic works as expected as long as data flows through the pipeline. But if I send a single batch of data, no output is produced unless a new batch of events ***pushes*** the data out, probably by advancing the watermarks.

My goal is to make sure that any data that enters the stream comes out as fast as possible, even if no events are sent afterwards. I have been trying different combinations of `WatermarkStrategy` without luck (which is where I believe my problem is located).

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: I'm curious why you didn't just do a `.keyBy(new KeySelectorForAllTypes()).window(blah).apply(new AllTypesJoinFunction)`?

Comment: @kkrugler To be honest, this is my first time ever working with Flink, and most of the progress I've been able to make is based on the Flink docs and other resources. Your suggestion is definitely worth trying!